# Jtable selected row in netbeans that is bounded to sql server

Tags: java, jtable

I fill a jtable(tbl_student) in netbeans by this code:

```
String[][] result;
    result = stu.Search(txt_search.getText());
    String hdr[] = {"code", "name", "family"};
    tbl_student = new JTable(result, hdr);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tbl_student);
    tbl_student.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

That Search() function is a select all query from a table in sql server database.
Now, I want to find selected row in this table. How can I do it?
My code in mouse click event of this jtable is not work!
What can I do?

Comment: could you provide more code, what is stu ? and what is its type ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get some data when you clicked a row in a JTable use the following code.

```
int row=tbl_student.getSelectedRow();
String Table_data=(tbl_student.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());  // In here 0 means the column number.

//If you have a JTable with 5 columns; 0 is the 1st column and 4 is the last (5th) column.
```

If you want to get data in a database table to a JTable, their is a library called rs2xml.jar with the help of that library you can simply fill a JTable with database data.

You can download that library from [HERE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/finalangelsanddemons/).

After downloading library use the following code to fill your JTable.

```
Connection conn=null;
ResultSet rs=null;
PreparedStatement pst=null;

   try{
        String sql="SELECT * FROM table_name"
        conn=java_connect.ConnecrDb();         //Database connecting class
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();

        tbl_student.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }

finally{
         try{
             rs.close();
             pst.close();
         }
         catch(Exception e){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);     
         }
       }
```